# Trying to Open a zip file that contains png pictures

Tags: python, png, zip

I've been having trouble opening a zip file that contains png images in it. I keep getting "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename_png.zip'

```
    import zipfile
    import os
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile('filename_png.zip')
    for f in archive.namelist():
        if f.endswith('/'):
            os.makedirs(f)
```

How do I make it so it loads the file and then I can load individual png pictures from said file?
I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Are you sure you have correct path to the zip file?

Comment: Try `print os.path.isfile('filename_png.zip')`

Comment: @Marcin I think so. If Peter's method came out false, does that mean it's wrong? Where can I fine the correct path? I've already looked at the file's properties....

Comment: @RachelGreen Try using absolute path instead of relative ones, e.g. "C:/Users/something/something2/filename_png.zip" if you in windows.

Comment: Try `print os.getcwd()`. This will show you where the script is looking for files. `cwd` is the `current working directory`. Or try `print os.path.abspath('filename_png.zip')` which shows you the full pathname Python uses to try and open the file, essentially `cwd + filename_png.zip`